# Wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I'm upgrading the project from Rails 3 project to Rails 5. Today I've encountered the strange error for me.

Now project is running on Rails 5. In project there are models `User` and `Article`. When I'm querying the `User` model, everything is fine:

```
User.all # returns all records 
User.first # returns first record
```

But when I'm querying the `Article` model, the same error appears for every query:

```
Article.all # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Atricle.first # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

The project uses the `devise` gem, the `User` model was created by this gem, but the `Article` model is not.

The question is how I can investigate this kind of problem? What approach should I use to find the source of error?

P.S.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :active, :description, :meta_d, :meta_k, :photo, :short_desc, :title, :photo_cache, :article_category_id, :tag_list, :tag_ids
  attr_accessor :main_slider, :main_photo, :main_photo_cache

  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  acts_as_taggable

  def normalize_friendly_id(text)
    text.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
  end

  belongs_to :article_category
end
```

Comment: How did you migrate? Meaning, did you run `rails new` for the new project and copied the contents such as controller, models ?

Comment: No, I just updated Gemfile and fixed compilation errors

Comment: Ok, so have you changed things such as `ActiveRecord` inheriting from `ApplicationRecord` and `Article` inheriting from `ApplicationRecord` ?

Comment: Is there any association b/w `User` and `Article` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, yes, `user` has_many `articles`, they're both models obviously

Comment: Ok, What I also did was add this `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true` in `application.rb`. Are you able to create a new `Article` ?

Comment: I have also `article` belongs_to `user`, so I don't need the `belongs_to_required_by_default`. I'm able to create new `Article` but I'm not able to query this article from table by `Article.find(id)`, it produces the same error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Comment: Can you post your model here ? `article.rb`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, yes, please look at the update in main section

Comment: You're model is still inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, it should be changed to `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, I fixed all models to ApplicationRecord (also added file for abstract class), but the problem is not gone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179308/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-megas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `FriendlyId` gem, I had to upgrade it to `5.2.0` version